# Navigation back causes page reload in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have a single page PHP application that fetches data from a third party API and outputs the items in a product grid. Clicking on one of the products leads to an external url which opens in the same window.

When using the back button in Chrome to go back på the application after clicking the external link, the page reloads for some reason. I'm only experiencing this problem in Chrome, therefore I'm wondering if it could be a Chrome related bug?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. It was caused by using a window load event incorrectly.